# Primes and Puzzles are my Passion. Combining them here to get Productive Prime Puzzles..Find the Missing Info

Tags: knowledge

$EXAMPLE$:

$997$  =  $O.$ $T.$.- $T.$   One Thousand - Three

$Expand$ on the Full Info of the following Prime clues.

A).  2 = F & O. E. P

B).   3 = S.P

C).   5 = F. On the H.

D).   7 = H. of R.

E).   11 = F. DD. P. P.

F).   13 = C. in a S.

G).   23 = L. in A. - T

H).   31 = I.C.F. at B.R.

I).   101 = D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard these referred to as "Language Equations".

Answers

> A) 2 = **F**irst & **O**nly **E**ven **P**rime
>  B) 3 = **S**econd **P**rime
>  C) 5 = **F**ingers on the **H**and
>  D) 7 = **H**ills of **R**ome
>  E) 11 = **F**irst **D**ouble **D**igit **P**alindromic **P**rime
>  F) 13 = **C**ards in a **S**uit
>  G) 23 = **L**etters in **A**lphabet - **T**hree
>  H) 31 = **I**ce **C**ream **F**lavours at **B**askin **R**obbins
>  I) 101 = **D**almations

Comment: That’s fast!!!.

Comment: @Uvc Admittedly, I've seen some of these before (like 13 and 31). Is 11 correct or am I missing something?

Comment: (Dalmatians). Great solve, well done @hex!!

Comment: @hexomino one P expansion is missing

Comment: Yes..one more P need to be filled

Comment: Great..all done..